# Is multithreading appropriate in this situation?

Tags: java, sql, database, multithreading

**Problem Description:**

We are given a task to write a Java program which connects to a database, executes an SQL Query, iterates the JDBC Resultset containing Millions of records and writes the data onto flat files.

**Proposed Solution:**

I thought of designing a solution based on Multithreading in Java.

**Thread 1:** I would have one thread whose only task is to iterate the Resultset, fetch each record, create a DTO object for each record, puts that DTO object onto a *java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue*.

**Thread 2:** This thread is expected only to pull each DTO object from the queue and write it to the Flat file.

**Constraint:** We are supposed to use no other API except Java

Do you feel this approach needs enhancements? or are there any better approaches than this, by which, performance can be enhanced, so that, it takes very less time to export million number of records to file?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: those export tools really do a great job, but, I am required to develop a Java program for this requirement.

Comment: Do you need a single flat file or could there be multiple files?

Comment: no only one single flat file is required to contain all the records. According to my colleague, when exported using tools available, the file size is approx 70MB.

Comment: How do you know that the number of threads is a bottleneck? Sounds like access to the file system would be the bottleneck here, in which case I don't see the point of using more than one thread (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Yeah, you probably are correct. Getting more threads to work on the file system will not help in any way. But need to work on it to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the first thread that has as task iterating the Resultset and get data.

I agree with the flat writing performed by a single thread as access to disk cannot be optimized by multi-threading.

But i would use a thread by a set of rows to prepare in a state ready to be written in the flat file.
The idea would be to have a structure that contains a set of arrays of bytes to write, the order in which the write should be performed and the next data to consume by the thread that performs writing. 
You would have a instance of this structure that would be shared between threads that prepare the data into bytes and the thread that performs the file writing.

So the idea would be to have some threads that prepares a set of rows (1000, 10 000, 100 000...you should make some tests to tweak the best value)  that performs a task enough expensive to have an interest to use threads to achieve this task.
Of course you must not start more threads than your machine have available threads during the launching of the task.
Otherwise the thread that performs writing in the file could have some inactivity periods. Which is undesirable.

The advantage of this solution is that the thread that performs writing in the flat file doesn't consume time any longer to transform dto properties in the good string format, just it writes bytes in the output stream.

Comment: Thanks, David. As you said, I am required even to transform the data present in DTO objects to UTF-8 format before writing them to the flat file. So, the thread which you were talking about, is best suited to carry out this work for every, let's say 100 DTO Objects. But, I think it requires to have another Queue to hold the bytes to be consumed and written by Thread 2.

Comment: Seems like I got something to work on. What if I start more threads than my CPU has. My CPU is 4C/8T. Does it mean that I cannot start more than 8 Java threads? I think Java's logical threads has nothing to do with CPU's actual threads.

Comment: You can use a queue but you should ensure that the queue is populated in the correct order for the consumer.

Comment: What matters is not core but cpu threads. "Does it mean that I cannot start more than 8 Java threads?" You can start as many threads as you want but you could not run simultaneously more threads as available cpu threads. A started thread and a running threads are different things. "I think Java's logical threads has nothing to do with CPU's actual threads. " In fact you have a relation between a Thread Java and a CPU thread.  A Java thread that is running is performed by a CPU thread.

Comment: So, you mean to say that, at any given point of time, I cannot have more than 8 Java threads running simultaneously.

Comment: Indeed, minus currently running threads of the OS and other applications.

Comment: Well the os juggles about a thousand threads from different apps simultaniously. Unless your workload is cpu bound, there is no need to worry about the thread arithmatic. In present case the workload is _heavily_ disk bound.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a BlockingQueue so that the writer thread waits for elements i the queue is empty. Also you will have limited options for backpressure if the writer is much slower than reader. BlockingQueue can be bounded to some size and force reader thread to wait before adding to queue. Also think about reading in batches. Try to test different approaches.

Comment: Ya, this is my another idea. I am thinking to have more than 1 thread for fetching DTO Objects from Queue and writing them onto the flat file

Answer (score 0):

There is a general rule i follow when i need to answer whether multithreading (MT) should be used. The rule is: run your program in single thread mode and watch the cpu usage in taskmanager. If the cpu belts at a constant 25% or constant 50% then it is highly probable that more threads can help. The percentage is actually `100/(no of cores)` so 25% on a i5 machine.

Even *with* this condition, MT may not be useful, for example if your task cannot be *effectively* parallelized. This is an experience and judgement thing. So implement MT and test. If cpu usage increases then good, otherwise revert your MT code.

Even *without* this condition, there are scenarios when more threads help. Example is gui code which has to wait for webservice call. Or when you need to implement some sort of timeout logic.

In almost all cases the improvement is minuscle and/or the added code complexity is not worth the gain. Do note that doing MT opens up ways of inducing difficult to catch bugs. So professionally i stick to the taskmanager thing even if MT looks more *cool* (sorry, but i just said it). Avoid MT unless it gives significant perf boost. Remember, writing code is the easy part. The tough part comes for the testers and the bugfixers.

Comment: Thanks, inquisitive. One more reason is, I may not be having just one table to export. I may have to export more than 1 table to different Flat files. As of now, we are having only one table. But in future, if we are told to export more than 1 table, I think it's good to use threads to start exporting multiple tables at a time instead of doing it one after the other.

Comment: Leave future for future. Design for the present. Google YAGNI.